# Find if user was redirected to a page by unauthorized (401) error doc using javascript?

Tags: javascript, apache, errordocument

Is it possible to find out if a user was redirected to a page via an unauthorized (401) error doc using javascript? The error docs are located in the vhost dir of the server, not using .htaccess